# Php Soap With Attachment

Tags: php, web-services, soap, attachment

I have to access to a web service in **Soap**. I use the **SoapClient** class of php for the commons calls :

That work without problems.

But, now I have to send a file in a Soap request as is describe in [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments).

The SoapClient class doesn't support the Soap with attachment.
I found [this solution](https://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/09/soap-client-attachments-php/), but it use `imap_mail_compose` function and I cannot use it.

I found others solutions that use Pear framework.

The document to join is a XML.

Have you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use imap_mail_compose?

Comment: Because it [requires](http://php.net/manual/en/imap.requirements.php) a PHP extension that is not installed on our system.